# Help make sense of these integral manipulations

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, dirac-delta

In the context of statistical mechanics (so functions of real output are often defined on a 2n dimensional vector space called the phase space, of whose measure I will indicate with $d\Gamma$ ), the following was written
$$\int_{H<E} d\Gamma= \int_0^E \int \delta(H(p,q)-\epsilon) d\Gamma d\epsilon$$
where H is a nowhere negative function of real output defined on all of phase space and the domain of integration of the first integral is to be understood as all points of phase space where H is less than E and when not specified the integration occurs over all phase space.

As far as I understood it, this is equivalent to the statement that
$$\int_0^E \int_{H=\epsilon} d\Gamma d\epsilon$$
is the first lefthand side integral I wrote. Can anyone help me make sense of this? I of course understand the intuition but how exactly does one "integrate over the domain of integration" in this manner? I'm interested in the rigorous way of doing this.

Comment: We can calculate the area of the unit disk by first integrating over every circle of radius $r\le 1$ which gives length $2\pi r$ and then integrate those over $r$ from zero to one. The formula $\int_0^E \int_{H=\epsilon} d\Gamma d\epsilon$ is just an analogue of this and the formula involving that delta function is a physicist's way of writing the same. I would however have used a different notation for the two dimensional measure $d\Gamma$ and the measure we use when we integrate over the level sets of $H\,.$